Using a Request scope service in an axios interceptor
I'm not a nest expert.
What I want is that when the application starts, I configure my axios (configureAxios call).
In this method, I configure an axios interceptor. I want all outgoing requests to have a correlation header from the correlationService.
Problem: this correlationService has a request scope. So, if I've understood correctly, for each incoming request, a new instance will be created and used during request processing.
So I don't know how to retrieve this "current" correlationService.
If I add the correlationService to the CustomModule constructor, as there's no instance at launch, the configureAxios method won't be called and outgoing requests won't get the header.
How can I do this? Thanks
@Module({
  imports: [
    CorrelationModule,
    HttpModule.registerAsync({
      useClass: CustomHttpConfig,
    }),
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: 'CustomHttpService',
      useExisting: HttpService,
    },
  ],
  exports: ['CustomHttpService'],
})
export default class CustomModule implements OnModuleInit {
  constructor(private readonly httpService: HttpService) {}
  
  onModuleInit(): any {
    CustomHttpConfig.configureAxios(this.httpService.axiosRef);
  }
}

@Injectable()
export default class CustomHttpConfig {

  public static configureAxios(axiosInstance: AxiosInstance) {
    axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(
      (config) => {
        config.headers['correlation'] = correlationService.correlation; #HERE
        return config;
      },
      (error) => {
        return Promise.reject(new ContractualisationErrorException(error.message));
      },
    );
  }
}

@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })
export default class CorrelationService {

  private _correlation?: string;

  get correlation(): string | undefined {
    return this._correlationId;
  }

  set correlation(value: string) {
    this._correlationId = value;
  }

}
I tried using refModule, but it couldn't find the correlationService instance, so I tried using NestInterceptor...
